# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible error

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, core-video

I am trying to create a CVOpenGLESTextureRef object from an existing 
CVImageBufferRef, like it's shown in docs

```
//Mapping a BGRA buffer as a renderbuffer:
 CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
```

And it returns `kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible` while the other example works correctly for the same pixel buffer.

```
//Mapping a BGRA buffer as a source texture:
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
```